# Getting requested reviewer names from a new TFS Code Review Workitem

Tags: c#, tfs

Using the TeamFoundation libraries in C#, I am getting a list of Work Items in a WorkItemStore object, then querying that object to find Work Item Type = 'Code Review Request and State = 'Requested'. I now need to process the resulting list and find the names of the requested reviewers for each Code Review Request; but I cannot find them anywhere on the returned objects.
Where do I need to look? If I need to link to another object, where and using what?
Thanks!

Comment: Field reference for code reviews is [here](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/jj153004.aspx) and there doesn't seem to be any "Requested Reviewers" field. And all of the field reference is [here](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms194971(v=vs.120).aspx)

Comment: Thank you Beytan. I had already looked through those lists and the only possibility I see is Required Attendee - which I will take a closer look at once my development system comes back up.

Comment: Required Attendee is a field in CMMI template which is not relevant to Reviewers you're looking for. Sorry just pointing out only the "no" part, I hope someone can help with more knowledge. Just tried to point that it is not available via WI fields.

Comment: Understood. I knew it was a long shot <smile>. Looks like my best chance to get Reviewers is to see if I can programmatically open the Review in Team Explorer. Looking in that direction now.

Answer (score 0):

This post on Code Review statistics took me on the last mile to the solution I needed: http://www.geoffmazeroff.com/2016/04/10/getting-code-review-statistics-programmatically-from-tfs/

In it, Geoff points out that each Code Review Request, which is related to a shelveset, when generated actually also creates a Code Review Response with the Reviewer the developer selected.

You can access the Reviewer name from the Code Review Response by examining the Code Review Response's Fields collection and looking for "Reviewed By"